# Changing the optimizer in the tensorflow object detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

How to change the optimiser for the configuration

for example the following is a confgi for ssd_coco_mobilenetv2

```
train_config: { 
  batch_size: 4 
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer: { 
      learning_rate: { 
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0001 decay_steps: 800720 decay_factor: 0.95 
        } 
      } 
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9 
      decay: 0.9 
      epsilon: 1.0 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is the [proto](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/optimizer.proto) file that corresponds to the optimizer. According to the proto file, you can choose among three different optimizers, e.g.

1. rms_prop_optimizer
2. momentum_optimizer
3. adam_optimizer

And then for each optimizer, you can configure the learning rate as one of the following

1. constant_learning_rate
2. exponential_decay_learning_rate
3. manual_step_learning_rate
4. cosine_decay_learning_rate

And then for each learning rate, you can configure what the values are, the default values are also provided by the proto file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try momentum_optimizer

```
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: 0.2
          total_steps: 2000
          warmup_steps: 0
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
}
```

In my observation this is sufficient to train objects which have repetitive geometric shapes (for example: a rectangular confinement, or a circular grain silo)